# Update Text on DateTimePicker Selection

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using [this](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker) for a modal date time picker. When a date is selected I run this method:

```
const handleConfirm = (date) => {
  hideDatePicker();
};
```

This makes sense, as I reference it in the modal date time picker:

```
<DateTimePickerModal
  isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
  onConfirm={handleConfirm}
  onCancel={hideDatePicker}
  date={props.value}
/>
```

I have a `Text` component and I want to update its text in the `handleConfirm` method to the new date. Here is my component:

```
<Text style={[styles.titleSize]}>
  {moment(props.value).format('MMM DD, YYYY')}
</Text>
```

Where `props.value` is the initial value of the date picker. How can I update the text when a new date is picked? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, if you want to show date selected in the `Text` you could use a state variable. So your code becomes:

```
const [dateSelected, setDateSelected] = useState(props.value); 

const handleConfirm = (date) => {
  hideDatePicker();
  setDateSelected(date);
};

<DateTimePickerModal
  isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
  onConfirm={handleConfirm}
  onCancel={hideDatePicker}
  date={props.value}
/>

<Text style={[styles.titleSize]}>
  {moment(dateSelected).format('MMM DD, YYYY')}
</Text>
```

Comment: Works! Thank you so much!!! New to RN so this helps a lot!

Comment: One thing: would you recommend any cross-platform modal pickers? So, not just for date, but for anything, like strings, numbers, etc. Thanks!

Comment: For modal pickers, textboxes, datepickers, textfields and so on I'm use [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/) components. I feel very confortable.

Comment: Yes of course. For react-native see [here](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui)